# How to convert a unicode string with str type to a real unicode string in python2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert a str string `'\u4e2d\u56fd'` to unicode `u'\u4e2d\u56fd'`. It's the same thing in python3, but how to do it in python2.7?

I have tried decode, encode, str, bytes, unicode and others, but they all didn't work.

```
a = '\u4e2d\u56fd'
b = u'\u4e2d\u56fd'
print a
print b
```

And the result of the code above is

```
\u4e2d\u56fd
中国
```

All I want to do is to convert a to b.

Thanks for any tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use raw_unicode_escape codec. For example:

```
a = '\u4e2d\u56fd'
a = a.decode('raw_unicode_escape')
print a
中国
```

Comment: This seems to be the most direct approach.

Answer (score 0):

you should write in the header of `.py` file `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = '\u4e2d\u56fd'
print a
```

or try that

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: try updated example @Woko when I was use python it helps me